# Not getting Sum of rows

Tags: mysql

I have written an SQL query to fetch records using group on some fields. I am getting the desired output but new requirement is to transform the returns so there are no duplicates,

my query

```
select t.chain_code,t.voucher_type,t.expired_on,

                (select sum(count(*)) from vouchers t2 where t.`chain_code` = t2.`chain_code` AND t.voucher_type=t2.voucher_type AND t2.expired_on=t.expired_on AND t2.`expired_on` < CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH ) as expiry_count,
                (select count(*) from vouchers t2 where t.`chain_code` = t2.`chain_code` AND t.voucher_type=t2.voucher_type AND t2.expired_on=t.expired_on ) as count

                from vouchers t GROUP BY `voucher_type`,chain_code
```

**Output**

```
select t.chain_code,t.voucher_type,t.expired_on,

                (select count(*) from vouchers t2 where t.`chain_code` = t2.`chain_code` AND t.voucher_type=t2.voucher_type AND t2.expired_on=t.expired_on AND t2.`expired_on` < CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH ) as expiry_count,
                (select count(*) from vouchers t2 where t.`chain_code` = t2.`chain_code` AND t.voucher_type=t2.voucher_type AND t2.expired_on=t.expired_on ) as count

                from vouchers t GROUP BY `voucher_type`,chain_code, expired_on

chain_code  voucher_type    expired_on  expiry_count    count   
EM  AD  0000-00-00 00:00:00 389 389 
EM  AD  2000-07-03 15:25:39 2   2   
EM  AD  2000-07-03 15:27:55 2   2   

LI  AD  0000-00-00 00:00:00 265 265 
LI  AD  2000-07-03 15:25:39 4   4   

ME  AD  0000-00-00 00:00:00 655 655 
ME  AD  2000-07-03 15:25:39 11  11  
ME  AD  2000-07-03 15:27:55 5   5   

RE  AD  0000-00-00 00:00:00 210 210 
RE  AD  2000-07-03 15:25:39 1   1
```

Need output as per below format

```
chain_code  voucher_type    expiry_count    count   
EM           AD              393              393             
LI           AD              269              269
```

and so on...

Sample data

```
voucher_id  chain_code  voucher_type    voucher_code    description expired_on  created_at  updated_at  is_active   online_voucher_code quote_id

1   VU  LO2D    838O3688R90196NE        2018-07-10 12:58:57 2018-07-10 12:58:57 2018-07-10 12:58:57 0   856N6221F41714HV    221 
2   VU  NL2D    111L8544K32250IB        2018-07-10 13:06:55 2018-07-10 13:06:55 2018-07-10 13:06:55 0   221W5963F34023UJ    221 
3   VU  LO2D    829B9151C57701TQ        2018-07-10 13:06:55 2018-07-10 13:06:55 2018-07-10 13:06:55 0   136P1874R95760BO    221 
4   VU  LO2D    206G7993R29994IC        2018-07-10 13:21:03 2018-07-10 13:21:03 2018-07-10 13:21:03 0   358T8470C62263PQ    228
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "duplicates"? There is no row given that holds both the `chain_code` `EM` and the `expiry_count` `393` in your example

Comment: I need unique chain_code, voucher_type and count of both expiry and total as a final output

Answer (score 0):

Have your subqueries as tables to JOIN instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.chain_code, t.voucher_type, count_expired as expiry_count, count_all as count
FROM vouchers t
JOIN (SELECT chain_code, voucher_type, COUNT(*) as count_all 
      FROM vouchers 
      GROUP BY chain_code, voucher_type) AS t2 ON t.chain_code = t2.chain_code AND t.voucher_type = t2.voucher_type
JOIN (SELECT chain_code, voucher_type, COUNT(*) as count_expired 
      FROM vouchers 
      WHERE expired_on < CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH 
      GROUP BY chain_code, voucher_type) AS t3 ON t.chain_code = t3.chain_code AND t.voucher_type = t3.voucher_type
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your sql but not getting desired output ...need output format as mentioned in my post .. thanks

Comment: Well that isn't very helpful, could you elaborate?

Comment: Need output as per below format

chain_code  voucher_type    expiry_count    count   
EM           AD              393              393             
LI           AD              269              269

Comment: You haven't added any sample data so it is hard to test the query

Comment: I have added sample data also ..pls check

Comment: Thanks a lot Joakim Danielson.. you saved my day :)